# Replacing Zero Values of a Field Using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

In computing the velocity and time of the flow path, the slope is needed but there are values in the field that are zero. How can I replace those zero values into 0.0001 so that the output of the computation will not be zero?

Answer (score 4):

Use the field calculator.  Either Select by Attributes where YourField = 0 and then calculate that field for all selected records to 0.0001, or with all or no records selected use:

Parser: VB Script

Show Codeblock: checked

Pre-Logic Script Code:

```
Output = [YourField]
If IsNull(Output) Then
  Output = 0.0001
ElseIf Output = 0 Then
  Output = 0.0001
End If
```

YourField:  Output

Answer (score 2):

Similar to [@Richard Fairhurst's](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/36413/richard-fairhurst) answer, if you want to use Python in the field calculator, you could try the following:

Parser: Python

Show Codeblock: Checked

Pre-Logic Script Code:

```
def fixSlope(slopeField):
  if slopeField is None:
    return 0.0001
  elif slopeField == 0:
    return 0.0001
  else:
    return slopeField
```

Expression:
(provided your field is called "Slope")

```
fixSlope( !Slope!)
```